# Can loopback use indexeddb for offline sync?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I started using loopback to create an API server. It has offline sync capability built in.
Can loopback framework use indexeddb for offline sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, loopback uses localStorage for offline storage. However, it should be reasonably easy to write a connector (adapter) for indexed db.

*Disclaimer: I am a LoopBack developer working for StrongLoop.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would really suggest you to switch/support indexeddb since it is really better/faster and doesn't have the 5mb limit of localstorage...